# Problemas com o Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, microsoft

Bom, eu não sei o que está acontecendo, pelo visto o problema é com o Net Framework. Porém, ele não aparece instalado no gerenciador de programas, deve ser pelo fato dele vir embutido com o Windows 10. Eu sei disso pois quando vou tentar instalar o Net Framework fala que eu já possuo uma versão instalada em meu computador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do Visual Studio você está utilizando neste caso? Qual .Net está instalado e qual versão do Windows?

Comment: Eu uso o Visual Studio 2017 Preview. Ele funciona bem e tem várias correções de bugs. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Comment: Utilizo o Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

Tente esse processo:

1. Feche o Visual Studio
2. Abra a pasta: %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\V9.0
3. Apague os seguintes arquivos:

   - toolbox.tbd
   - toolbox_reset.tbd
   - toolboxIndex.tbd
   - toolboxIndex_reset.tbd
4. Abra o Visual Sudio
5. Selecione "Reset Toolbox"

Isso resolve quase 100% dos casos. Se isto não resolver, eu creio que exista mais de uma versão do Visual Studio instalada.